# Mutual information of a random subset

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Suppose we sample the following two random variables, for some large integer $n$:

1. Let random variable $X_1$ be a uniformly random subset of $m$ elements chosen from set $[n]:=\{1,\dots,n\}$, where $m < n$.
2. Let random variable $X_2$ be a uniformly random subset of $k$ elements of $X_1$, where $k<m$.

In other words, $X_2$ is a random subset of $X_1$, and $X_1$ is a random subset of $[n]$.

**My Question:** Does it hold that, for any random variable $Y$ that determines $X_2$ (i.e. $I[ X_2 : Y ] = H[X_2]$), the amount of information that $Y$ contains about $X_2$ is never larger than the amount of information that it reveals about $X_1$?
Formally,
$$
I[ X_2 : Y ] ≤ I[ X_1 : Y ] ? 
$$

I think this should be true, because whatever we learn from $Y$ about $X_2$ is also "useful" information about $X_1$. But how can I formalize this intuition?

**Update:** Assume that $Y$ that determines $X_2$, i.e. $I[ X_2 : Y ] = H[X_2]$.

Comment: I don't understand the connection between $Y$ and $X_1$ or $X_2$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: I added a clarification

Answer (score 1):

You can see you conjecture is false by looking at the special case $Y=X_2$. Then $I(X_1;Y)= H(X_2) - H(X_2|X_1) \le H(X_2)=I(X_2;Y)$

In general:

Since $X_2 = g(Y)$, $H(X_1 | Y) \le H(X_1 | X_2)$

Then

$$\begin{align}
I(X1;Y) &= H(X_1) - H(X_1 | Y) \\
&\ge H(X_1) - H(X_1 | X_2) \\
&= H(X_2)- H(X_2|X_1) \\
&=I(X_2;Y) - H(X_2|X_1) \\
&=I(X_2;Y) - \log \binom{m}{k}
\end{align}$$

That's all you can say.